# git merge branch in a zipper like fashion

Tags: git, git-branch

i have an Git repo with for example two branches "master" and "other". They contain commits almost to one subfolder each, so there is no collision at revision time in history. Now I like to delete the branch "other"; and merge it's commits into "master" in a zipper-like fashion, eg:

```
Master A1 A2 -  -  -  M3 M4  
Other  B1 -  -  -  B2 -  -   B3
```

becomes

```
Master A1 B1 A2 B2 M3 M4 B3
```

and "other" vanishes. So only one linear master branch is left.

Is this possible with Git's toolkit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, are you sure this is what you want to do? There are two fairly standard solutions for this sort of situation in Git, but neither of them "zips" the commits up in exactly the way you want. The first option is just to merge "other" into "master", and delete the "other" branch. This does not leave you with a linear history, but everything is in the "master" branch, and you can look at the revisions in any particular order that you want (for instance, you can do `git log --date-order` to get the commits listed in the order that you want). You will get this history in the end:

```
    A1 A2 M3 M4
    *--*--*--*
   /          \
--*            *-- < master
   \          /
    *----*---*
    B1   B2  B3
```

You would achieve this by running:

```
git checkout master
git merge other
git branch -d other
```

The other option is to rebase your "other" branch on top of your master branch. This will give you a linear history, but all of your commits on the "other" branch will appear after the commits on "master." The dates will be preserved, so if you want to know when the commits actually happened, you can still find that out, but topologically, they'll be sorted afterwards:

```
  A1 A2 M3 M4 B1 B2 B3
--*--*--*--*--*--*--*-- < master
```

You can do this by running:

```
git checkout other
git rebase master
git checkout master
git merge other
git branch -d other
```

If you're absolutely certain that neither of the above work for you, you can consider the "zipper" approach that you're trying to do. There are no automated tools that come with Git that will do this for you, so you're going to have to work a little harder for this. It will also cause problems for anyone who is basing their history on `master`, as they will all then have to rebase their work on top of your new `master` (your proposed linear history changes the parents of each of the commits in master, which means that those commits are different than they were before, which means that anyone else is now basing their work on an entirely new set of commits, that just happen to have the same diffs as the previous set of commits).

If you don't mind doing the ordering manually, you could use `git rebase -i` to order the commits however you want. You would run the following commands (where `base` is the first commit before the two branches diverged; if `a1` is the first commit not in common between them, then you could use `a1~` to refer to this commit):

```
 git checkout master
 git merge other
 git rebase -i base
```

During the interactive rebase, you will presented with a text file containing a list of changes, which you can edit into whichever order you want them to be applied in. This is entirely manual, of course, so only an option if you have a short history and want to rearrange the commits manually. If there are any merge conflicts, you may have to resolve them manually multiple times if you do this. And as mentioned, this will mean that anyone else who was basing their work on `master` will now have to rebase as well.

You could also automate this process somewhat, by creating a new branch starting at `base`, and cherrypicking commits from one branch or the other to this new one, and finally replacing `master` with this new branch.

But as I mentioned, you probably don't want to do this. My first two solutions, which don't give you quite the history that you're looking for, but do give you something close to it, will behave the best in most Git-based workflows.

Comment: Yes, the motivation for the "zipper" was to have a ordninary history as it would look like if the modifications would have been done to one branch instead two ones. That is possible as they happened in two distinct subfolders. The question is if I now do the `git rebase -i` manual work or just resign and stay with a usual rebased history with their counterintuitive unordered timeline.

Comment: @user702867 I would recommend, if you work with Git, that you don't worry about having an ordered, linear timeline. Accept the fact that you are doing branched development; you can choose to either have an ordered, nonlinear timeline (as in my first suggestion), or a linear timeline in which each individual branch is ordered intuitively, but the whole thing isn't (as in my second suggestion).

Comment: I think in your option 2 you still need the `git merge other` after checking out master, but it will be a fast-forward merge.

Comment: @Karl You're absolutely right, managed to leave that out somehow the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could merge Other into Master, then run a `git rebase -i A1` to interactively rebase - rearrange the commits in the text editor to your liking. You'd still have a merge commit to deal with, probably.

And I wouldn't rebase if you've already pushed to another repository otherwise you'd be changing history and the commits wouldn't line up.

Comment: Tried that now, well it doesn't work: The interactive mode only displays the rebased commits, but not the ones on master branch after the rebase location. Thus it is not possible to intertwene "master" and "other" commits by that way.

Comment: Ok, maybe I misunderstood.. Your comment leads to a solution: First i `rebase` "other" onto "master". Then i `rebase -i` master onto A1. Now the interactive list shows commits of both branches since A1. I can now rearrange them. Alhtough that have to be done with extreme caution as one could easily swap commits order and thus producing a strange history.

Comment: Yeah, care should always be taken when rebasing. With great power comes great responsibility. Also, thank god for `reflog`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the actual order of commits and this would be OK:

A1 A2 M3 M4 B1 B2 B3

Then on branch Other do `git rebase master`.

Answer (score 0):

Create another branch named `temp`. `git cherry-pick` relevant commits in order into `temp`. Rename branch `temp` to `master`: `git branch -M master`.

Comment: It seems I do that with `rebase -i` as explained above so I can edit the list of all commits interactively. Or is there any possibility to do this wirh `git cherry-pick` too?

Comment: Rebasing should be easier. Cherry-picking is a bit more work.